# Refund customer in-app purchase but BillingClient still indicate user has purchased?

Tags: android, android-billing

I'm using the following `BillingClient`.

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2.2'
```

Although I have issued refund as bellow

[image]

But I'm still getting the following respond from `BillingClient.queryPurchases`

```
{
  "orderId": "GPA.3352-2555-5719-25534",
  "packageName": "com.yocto.wenote",
  "productId": "note_list_promo",
  "purchaseTime": 1560501011137,
  "purchaseState": 0,
  "purchaseToken": "djjneabakdaenkjafajbbclo.AO-J1OzbDNn5WkobYbSqLNzoBokm1F552-CqzfLQuNXK69bhxC-TnOTqdPV1RCl9T2okpSWfRD9RrE0eFhSN8glUbsOM5XUBDRnm_yK2Ohq_uyNuU17i1dc3CBhdeEn9uZCIfD3zY4tF"
}
```

---

According to documentation of `BillingClient.queryPurchases`

> Get purchases details for all the items bought within your app. This
>   method uses a cache of Google Play Store app without initiating a
>   network request.

This might be the reason. I try with another function - `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` wouldn't help either. According to documentation

> Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even
>   if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.

**For queryPurchaseHistoryAsync, there are no `purchaseState` to indicate the following purchase is cancelled!**

```
{
  "productId": "note_list_promo",
  "purchaseToken": "djjneabakdaenkjafajbbclo.AO-J1OzbDNn5WkobYbSqLNzoBokm1F552-CqzfLQuNXK69bhxC-TnOTqdPV1RCl9T2okpSWfRD9RrE0eFhSN8glUbsOM5XUBDRnm_yK2Ohq_uyNuU17i1dc3CBhdeEn9uZCIfD3zY4tF",
  "purchaseTime": 1560501011137,
  "developerPayload": null
}
```

---

Google should really provide a non-cached version of `queryPurchases`.

Any idea what I have done wrong? I don't wish users can continue using paid features, after I have issued the refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We clear the cache in the following way

```
private static void clearGooglePlayStoreBillingCacheIfPossible(BillingClient billingClient) {
    billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(SkuType.INAPP, (responseCode, purchasesList) -> {
    });

    billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(SkuType.SUBS, (responseCode, purchasesList) -> {
    });
}
```

After that, we will call `BillingClient.queryPurchases` as usual.

Take note, such cache clearing doesn't happen immediately. It may take as long as 24 hours, for the cache to be cleared. Strangely, this important requirement isn't documented any way.

Comment: How it works? You just call `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` two times... and?

Comment: The purpose is to trigger cache clearing so that `BillingClient.queryPurchases` will return correct value. But, the cache clearing wouldn't happen immediately. It may delay as long as 24 hours.

Comment: It's not "clearing". You just call the same function but asynchronously. And there is no purpose for doing this, because it do NOTHING. The purchase from `queryPurchases` removes after sometime for some other reason without calling this code which is absolutely senselessly.

Comment: No. It wouldn't. We run in live production and we know the current behavior of `queryPurchases`. This is a known problem - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/122#issuecomment-502433585