# Refunded purchase still appearing in purchase list (Google in-app billing API)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm testing IAP with the Google in-app billing API in my Android app. I've made a test purchase, then did a refund on the Google Play Console. I can see the order status is now refunded.

However, when I run the app, I can see that the `BillingClient` can still find the purchase that was refunded (matched the same order number as the refunded order).

It was working before on previous refunds, but not anymore. I believe the issue is that `queryPurchasesAsync` may be using a cached result and not getting the latest purchases that the user has made.

Based off [Refund customer in-app purchase but BillingClient still indicate user has purchased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594713/refund-customer-in-app-purchase-but-billingclient-still-indicate-user-has-purcha), it was suggested to call `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` to try to clear the cache. I've done this and waited 24 hours but still can see the purchase in the purchase list.

Is there something going wrong here?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I faced the same issue.

Comment: I'm also currently having this problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but then i realised I did'n check the "Remove entitlement" checkbox when refunding in the console... If you don't check it - the client gets refund, but keeps the purchase :) so the product is indeed returned when you query it in the app.

Answer (score 1):

If you refund the purchase from Google Play Developer Console, you can do it like this(remember to check `Remove entitlement` checkbox)

[image]

Comment: As of this writing this is not true. I have checked that icon during refund and queryPurchaseHistoryAsync still returns PurchaseHistoryRecord with refunded item.